# Keep losing incremental variable within for loop

Tags: javascript

I've been fiddling with this for way too long and can't seem to get it working as it should.
The problem I'm having is that I'm losing the value of my incremental variable in a for loop, specifically when it goes in to the if statement that I have inside of it.  Ideally i want to iterate through an array until I find the correct value, attach a variable to that value and use it outside of the for loop.  This is the structure of the array I'm working with.

```
var dXId = [
 {url:"url1", dId:"id1"},
 {url:"url2", dId:"id2"},          
 {url:"url3", dId:"id3"}
];
```

And here is the loop that I'm running everything through:

```
for(i=0; i < dXId.length; i++) {
    if (dXId[i].url == currentUrl){
    var dataXuId = dXId[i].dId;
    break;
    }
```

}

The incremental 'i' variable always reverts back to 0 within the if statement.  It's odd, the dXId[i].url comes up correctly, but the dXId[i].dId pulls the first entry and 'i' seems to be lost after that. I'm sure there is a very simple solution to this, but javascript is something that I just always seem to have trouble with.

Comment: Literally at the beginning of the `for` loop, @DanielA.White

Comment: @eric_lagergren not necessarily

Comment: @DanielA.White well he sets `i=0` in the loop, and the loop will take that over, say, a global. See: jsfiddle.net/6GGzc/

Comment: it.  I'd been fiddling around for so long changing little things here and there that I'd forgotten about it.  But I did appreciate the explanations because I honestly have had a hard time getting my head around why you'd use == sometimes and why you'd use === at other times.  It makes more sense to me now.

The actual issue I'd had was in regards to something outside of what I posted.  I'd set one variable toLowerCase and without even thinking about it did not have the other one set to that.  Very frustrating, most of all because it was such a simple error that I should have caught.

Answer (score 4):

You are setting dXId[i].url = currentUrl inside your for loop instead of comparing with '=='. That could be part of the problem.

**EDIT**

As suggested by Eric...

The == Operator is to loosely compare the value of things, and the === is to strictly compare the value and type of things.

Examples:
Given x=10;

```
x == '10'  // true
x == 10    // true
x === '10' // false
x === 10   // true
```

Comment: If he's comparing strings he should use `===`

Answer (score 1):

You have mistake in your if syntax.. you are assigning value of `currentUrl` to variable `dXId[i].url`

```
if (dXId[i].url = currentUrl){

...

}
```

It should be changed to `===` to compare string values.

```
if (dXId[i].url === currentUrl){

...

}
```

After that, it works! Example also here: **[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fk5TA/)**

Thus, it is rather funny that JavaScript lets do such things in the first place: Assigning value to a variable in if block should definitely not be allowed.

For example consider the following snippet:

```
var foo = 1, // change to 0 and console.log will not be displayed
    bar;     // undefined

// Assigning value of foo to bar
if (bar = foo){

    // Will print out 1
    console.log("bar is: " + bar);

}
```

Will result to a printing following output to the console:

> bar is: 1

The reason being that `if (bar = foo){` is equals to `if (1){` which allows program to continue inside the if block :) ... if value of 0 is used for foo, console.log will not be displayed. (This is the behaviour at least which I tested using google chrome.)

Example about this in **[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K72b5/1/)**